# IOS String Localization stops working when adding additional localization

Tags: ios, xcode, ios5

I have created an new Xcode project and trying to setup string localization.

I have added a new file called
"localization.strings' with the following content.

"Login" = "English text2";

I have added the second localization to the Project > Info section in the latest version of Xcode.

I then tick the box on the right to add French for the localization.strings file. Once this is added I can run/build the application but the strings no longer link to this file.

For example, if i update the original english version above, to "testing text eng" for example, it still shows the original English text2.

Any idea why this might occur? The app is too large to post and there are no build errors, the file is not corrupt, missing, incorrect encoding.

Comment: The issue occurs once I click Make localised... on the localization.stings file.

Once this is clicked the strings do not link to this file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to make a clean build and delete the app from the simulator and/or your device, and then everything should work. You only need to do this once.

Before you added any localizations, your strings file would end up in the root of your application bundle, e.g. `MyApp.app/Localizable.strings`. This would then be copied into the Simulator and/or your device when you run the app.

After adding a localization, the file's contents is moved into localization-specific subdirectories such as `MyApp.app/en.lproj/Localization.strings` and `MyApp.app/fr.lproj/Localization.strings`. But the old file in the root bundle is still hanging around in the Simulator and on your device, and that's being found before the others. So do a clean build, delete the app from the Simulator and your devices and that old file will be removed.

Comment: I am only testing on the simulator for this app. I have reset the simulator and completely restarted xcode and run a new build but the old text still persits. I have also completely removed both of the localization.string files completely from the project so they are no more - yet the label still reads "English Test2" like it is still cached somewhere?

Comment: You need to combine resetting the simulator with a clean build. Hold alt and select "Product->Clean Build Folder" for a full clean.

Comment: Glad it worked. And like I said before, you don't need to do this every time, just once to get rid of the old file hanging around.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the only issue than can occur. I encounter an other case : two files with the same name : "Localizable.strings".
I had one in a library folder and one in the main project folder. The localization system only used one of them and not both.
I solved the issue by deleting the one that was not necessary.